# How to construct such a function?

Tags: analysis, summation

Suppose we have a function $f:X\rightarrow\Bbb K$ with $\Bbb K=\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$. Assume we have a sequence of functions $(g_N)_{n\in\Bbb{N}}$ with $g_N:X\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ and $g_1(x)\leq g_2(x)\leq g_3(x)\leq \ldots$ such that the sequence turns pointwise to $f$. Can someone construct a sequence $(h_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, $h_n:X\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ such that the following holds:
$$|f-g_N|\leq\sum_{n\geq N}h_n$$

Do someone have to use the pointwise convergence?! Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use  $h_n=g_{n+1}-g_n$ and then have $f-g_N=\sum_{n\ge N} h_n$.

Comment: because it is an telescoping series?

Comment: @Int35 Yes. $g_N+\sum_{n=N}^m h_n=g_m\to f$